# How to reference web.config from sub-directory

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Would anyone mind explaining to me in detail if it is possible to reference a web.config file for an ASP.NET application within a sub-directory, and if it is possible could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear what your asking — you might want to reword the question to make clear the problem. However, in ASP.Net controls, a URL that looks like

```
/foo/bar/picture.jpg
```

is *absolute* and is anchored at the server root.

A URL that looks like

```
foo/bar/picture.jpg
```

is *relative* with respect to the current URL.

Finally, URLs that look like

```
~/foo/bar/picture.jpg
```

are anchored to the root of the current web app. You might want to take into consideration the fact that web apps **can be nested**.

How URLs are referenced really has nothing to do with web.config. There is, however, an search and inheritance hierarchy for config data, along with scoping rules for that data. **[See the documentation for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178685(v=vs.100).aspx#scope_of_configuration_settings)**.

Answer (score 0):

Find mydomain.com/folder in IIS.  Right-click it and pick "Convert to application"  This will tell IIS to treat /folder as its own application, instead of just another folder inside the mydomain.com application.